# make zone under modal Controller scrollable

Tags: swift, modalviewcontroller

i looking for solution to make controller under modal presented controller active (scrollable), i have main scroll and alert (AlertController) which presented over main scroll. When alert presented, main scroll should be also active.

```
func showOkAlert(with title: String = "AppName", and message: String, closure: (()->Void)? = nil){
    let alert = BagitAlertController(title: message, image: UIImage(named: "checked-large")!)
    alert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In case if do this impossible with controller, i will make it as addSubview()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the viewcontroller is presented modally then the user interaction is not available for the main viewcontroller in the back. To make the user interaction possible for the main viewcontroller then add the view as a subview. Again the interactions on the subview will not be identified by the main view controller(in the back).

If you want that user should be able to interact with the main back view controller you have to subclass the modally presented viewcontroller and pass the touch events to the superview which will be main viewcontroller in the back.

Hope this helps.